# How can I randomly seperate a list into 2 lists but with same length

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a function that wants to seperate one list to 2 lists with same length and random list items

code:

```
def playersorting(playerslist):
        random.shuffle(playerslist)
        cut = random.randint(0, len(playerslist))
        list_1 = playerslist[:cut]
        list_2 = playerslist[cut:]

        print(list_1)
        print(list_2)


playerslist = ['amin', 'hasan', 'reza', 'mohsen', 'alireza', 'mahdi', 'daniyal', 'komeil']
playersorting(playerslist)
```

output is like:

```
['mohsen', 'hasan', 'mahdi', 'daniyal', 'reza', 'alireza']
['amin', 'komeil']
```

```
['daniyal', 'amin', 'komeil', 'reza', 'mahdi', 'hasan', 'alireza', 'mohsen']
[]
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
['daniyal', 'reza', 'hasan', 'alireza']
['komeil', 'mahdi', 'mohsen', 'amin']
```

random with same length

Comment: if you want to divide a list into 2 same sized lists, then why are you taking `cut` as a random number? Just do `cut = len(playerslist)//2`

Comment: @RustamGarayev Tnx...It worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you need to change your `cut` variable

```py
import random

l = ['amin', 'hasan', 'reza', 'mohsen', 'alireza', 'mahdi', 'daniyal', 'komeil']
half_len = len(l)//2

random.shuffle(l)

l1 = l[:half_len]
l2 = l[half_len:]

print(l1, l2)
```

```
['mahdi', 'amin', 'mohsen', 'reza'] 
['komeil', 'alireza', 'hasan', 'daniyal']
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use [`random.sample()][1]`:

```
from random import sample

def playersorting(playerslist):
    list_1 = sample(playerslist, len(playerslist) // 2)
    list_2 = [player for player in playerslist if player not in list_1]
    print(list_1)
    print(list_2)


playerslist = ['amin', 'hasan', 'reza', 'mohsen', 'alireza', 'mahdi', 'daniyal', 'komeil']
playersorting(playerslist)
```

Explanation:

1. `random.sample()` takes in an array, `population`, and a number, `k`, and returns a new array of length `k` of randomly selected elements from the array `population`.
2. So `sample(playerslist, len(playerslist) // 2)` returns an array of length `len(playerslist) // 2` of randomly selected elements from `playerslist`.
3. `[player for player in playerslist if player not in list_1]` returns every element in `playerslist` that is not already inside the first half of random elements.

Though the [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) method is advised.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def playersorting(playerslist):
    random.shuffle(playerslist)
    list_1 = playerslist[0:4]
    list_2 = playerslist[4:8]

    print(list_1)
    print(list_2)


playerslist = ['amin', 'hasan', 'reza', 'mohsen', 'alireza', 'mahdi', 'daniyal', 'komeil']
playersorting(playerslist)
```

Answer (score 0):

`randint` just return a integer value ranged from `[0,len(playerslist))`, so use `cut` to slice the list will ends with random two different length.

Simplely, you can just:

```py
def playersorting(playerslist):
        random.shuffle(playerslist)
        cut = int(len(playerslist) / 2)
        list_1 = playerslist[:cut]
        list_2 = playerslist[cut:]

        print(list_1)
        print(list_2)
```